# Prevent <dialog> from closing on keydown Esc in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dialog

Google Chrome closes `<dialog>` elements when Esc is pressed. Seems to be reacting to keydown.

Firefox does not. This is the expected behavior, as closing on any key press is easy to implement.

How to make Google Chrome leave dialogs open on Esc?

Please see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zeqo7kaf/1/

I have implemented `window`'s, `document`'s, `body`'s, `dialog`'s key events (up, down and pressed) to prevent propagation, however it seems to me that this is above dom events.

(in order to see dialogs in Firefox, go to `about:config` and set property `dom.dialog_element.enabled` to `true`).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can try to use `cancel` event: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/cancel_event)

```
dialog.addEventListener('cancel', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Modified JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7et3hf8p/

Comment: The `cancel` event documentation is now under [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement), which is a bit unfortunate because the page for [`HTMLDialogElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement) does not have a good example for it, and only lists the `close` event that seems to fire only after the dialog is closed.

Also in Chrome, pressing Esc twice still seems to close it even after preventing... In Firefox it works as expected

Answer (score 0):

### React Solution

Since the `cancel/close` events fire after the fact, I got this working by adding a keydown listener to the document itself.

```
const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
  if (e.key !== 'Escape') return;
  if (!allowDialogDismiss) e.preventDefault();
}

useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);

  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
  };
}, [allowDialogDismiss]);
```

The dialog doesn't dismiss on ESC key press anymore.

---

I have a text input inside the dialog and pressing ESC by mistake would mean losing the text input before it is saved. This worked. I change the `allowDialogDismiss` state depending on the input's text.